# Access UNION and JOIN query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

**Situation:** The Access database I'm working on separates parts into left and right parts. The same part can be used on both sides. I am trying to create a query to count the total number of individual parts needed per week.

**Question:** How do I create a query that allows to UNION multiple fields and JOIN as shown below?

```
Table 1:
Part # |Left Part | Left Part Qty | Right Part | Right Part Quantity
1        xyz         5               lmn          7
2        abc         8               xyz          4

Table 2:
Part # | Needed
1        10
2        25

Query:
Part | Quantity
xyz    150 (5 * 10) + (4 * 25) 
abc    200 (8 * 25) 
lmn    70 (7 * 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in MS Access, because you cannot put a `union`/`union all` into a subquery.  If you have a table of parts (which you should have), then you can use `left join`, so I think the following does what you want:

```
select p.partname,
       sum(nz(t1l.leftpartqty * t2.needed) + nz(t1r.rightpartqty * t2.needed))
from ((part as p inner join
       table2 as t2
       on p.part# - t2.part# 
      ) left join
      table1 as t1l
      on t1l.leftpart = p.partname 
     ) left join
     table1 as t1r
     on t1r.rightpart = p.partname
group by p.partname;
```

If you don't have such a table, you can use a view to do the `union all` and proceed from there.

Comment: Are you sure that `union` cannot be used as a subquery?

Comment: Please, see my answer. It's possible to use `union` as a subquery.

Comment: @MaciejLos . . . When I google "MS Access union subquery", I get numerous questions on many sites with the error that this is not allowed.  When I look at the documentation on the syntax for `select` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208930(v=office.12).aspx), there is no `union` as part of the `select` statement (it is a separate operator).  And, the definition of a subquery only allows `select`.

Comment: I use MS Access 2010 (MS Office 2010 Pro) and i've got no error ;) Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well:

```
SELECT T.Part, SUM(T.Qty * S.Needed) AS Quantity
FROM (
SELECT A.[Part#] AS PartNo, A.LeftPart As Part, A.LeftPartQty As Qty
FROM Table1 AS A
UNION ALL
SELECT B.[Part#] AS PartNo, B.RightPart As Part, B.RightPartQty As Qty
FROM Table1 AS B
) AS T INNER JOIN Table2 AS S ON T.PartNo = S.[Part#]
GROUP BY T.Part
ORDER BY T.Part
```

Result:

```
Part    Quantity
abx     200
lmn     70
xyz     150
```

For further information, please see:
[UNION (MS Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821131.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
[Subqueries (MS Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192664.aspx)
[INNER JOIN Operations (MS Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197346.aspx)
[LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN Operations (MS Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff198084.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)